# Can I evaluate a block inside a Proc?

Tags: ruby, proc, yield-keyword

Can I yield a block inside a Proc? Consider this example:

```
a = Proc.new do
  yield
end

a.call do
  puts "x"
end
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to print `x`, but interpreting this with ruby 2.0 raises `LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't, because the Proc you've created is an independent `yield` - that is, it's a `yield` that has no block in its context. Although you can call procs with specified parameters and thereby pass the parameters into the proc, `yield` doesn't work based on specified parameters; it executes the block found within the proc's closure. And the proc's closure is predefined; it is not modified just because you call it later with a block.

So it's equivalent of just typing 'yield' straight into `irb` (not within any method definitions) which returns the `LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)` error.

Answer (score 4):

@Rebitzele has explained why your code doesn't work: the `yield` keyword is shorthand notation for calling an anonymous block that has been passed to a method, and in this case there *isn't* even a method.

But you can of course give the block a name and then call it like you would call any other callable object:

```
a = ->&block { block.() }

a.() do puts 'x' end
# x
```

Comment: Still trying to figure out what's going on here, but this doesn't seem to work for me: `obj.instance_eval { def wrap(&block); a = ->&block { block.() }; a.() { puts 'goodbye' }; end}; obj.wrap { puts 'hello'; yield }` will only print `goodbye`